# NativeScript Angular Cannot use Frame in App.component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, nativescript

I am trying to put Frame in app.component.html, but it gives an error. What is wrong with my code?

Please see it on
[Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=MJeeW9)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular world you use `page-router-outlet` instead of `Frame`.

Checkout [official docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation) for more on navigation with Angular.

Comment: Where do I put my custom side drawer object? When I put it next to page-router-outlet they push each other.

Comment: Refer the [Official Drawer Navigation Template](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/tns-template-drawer-navigation-ng).

Comment: But what if I want to use my own custom side drawer? Could you please add it to your answer? And also how I show two pages at the same time? Thank you.